# Expressions for "a wish dedicated to one self"

Tags: expressions, word-usage, phrase-requests, expression-choice

I was translating a short story about a mortician (someone who does makeup for the dead) when I came across an idea I don't know how to express. In the story, the protagonist was talking about her dying wishes, one of which was that her apprentice would be the one to embalm her when she dies. Apparently, this was the **only** wish that was "dedicated" to herself, others were probably "dedicated" to others e.g. having her dog taken care of after she dies. I ended up writing:

> She said, “When I go, you must be the one who does my makeup. Don’t let any stranger touch my body.” **That was her only wish dedicated to herself.**

But it doesn't feel right to me. "Dedicated" doesn't seem to be the appropriate word and the sentence is clumsy. Are there better ways to express the idea?

Comment: Her only wish for herself

Comment: As Xanne says. Or "her only personal request".